# union a collection with missing values laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, collections

i am trying to add missing values to a collection that results my database table containing multiple items.

What i am trying to attempt is to add the items that are missing from collection as union values.

```
Collection {#217 ▼

 #items: array:7 [▼

0 => {#397 ▼

  +"item_id": 1

  +"amount": "4"

}

1 => {#402 ▼

  +"item_id": 3

  +"amount": "1"

}

2 => {#396 ▶}

3 => {#213 ▶}

4 => {#399 ▶}

5 => {#400 ▶}

6 => {#398 ▶}

]

}
```

i used union but it's not working,it makes a spererate array

```
$union = $collection->union([2 => ['0']]);
```

i don't want separate arrays and repeating items.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$union = $collection->merge([2 => ['0']]);
```

Comment: Can you explain that further such that others can learn from it? Why should one try that?

Comment: it will append  2  in the end.I want to append if 2 doesn't exist in the collection already.Also it's possible that there maybe many more items to append 2,3,4,6,99

Comment: check by using $collection->contains('2') then mege if doesnot exist